# JDeveloper 12c and Oracle ADF Mobile(android)

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

Hello I followed the procedure to build and deploy android Application on emulator using Jdeveloper 12c  .the Oracle link for the procedure is this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_app/tut_jdev_maf_app.html
 try to deploy my app on the android emulator for testing it gave  me these Errors:

`[05:57:57 PM] Signing application...
[05:57:57 PM] Command-line executed: ["C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\jarsigner", -keystore, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\Omile.keystore", -storepass, madu123, -keypass, madu123, -digestalg, SHA1, -sigalg, MD5withRSA, "C:\JDeveloper\mywork\Employees\deploy\Omile\Employees.apk", Omile]
[05:57:57 PM] jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: Omile.  Omile must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
[05:57:57 PM] Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)
[05:57:57 PM] Command-line executed:  "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\jarsigner" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\Omile.keystore" -storepass madu123 -keypass madu123 -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA "C:\JDeveloper\mywork\Employees\deploy\Omile\Employees.apk" Omile
[05:57:57 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[05:57:57 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[05:57:57 PM] Deployment failed due to one or more errors returned by 'C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\jdk\bin\jarsigner'.  The following is a summary of the returned error(s):
Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)`

Please i am new to Jdeveloper what should i do to rectify the Challenge?